# What is the best way to check consistency of Junits

Tags: java, junit, automation

What is the best way to check consistency of Junits , in other words what is the best way to automate junit execution of a project and to get it retry for configured no of times ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I understand correctly you want a way to automate the runin of jUnit Test, for my case I'm using maven and for launching tests I just use     `mvn test`

Comment: mvn test is fine but there are certain tests which are inconsistent e.g might fail after 5-10 executions , I wanted to know whats the best way to retrigger junits through maven multiple times( automated way not manually)

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to run several jUnit tests with one command with Suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({

   Test1.class,

   Test2.class,

   Test3.class,

   ...

})

public class MySuite {}

}
```